# Selecting the company with the highest number of sales of the most costly product

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table of all the sales records of many products, by different companies. Every record includes the product sold, the price it was sold for, the name of the company who sold it (note that the same product can be sold for any possible price). Example table structure:

```
id | product | sales_price | company
---+---------+-------------+---------
1  | prod122 | 123376456   | abcSales
2  | prod123 | 345676433   | xyzSales
3  | prod122 | 346876543   | xyzSales
4  | prod124 | 124688533   | wpwSales
```

I am trying to find out which company has the highest number of sales of the most pricey product. In other words, I want to write a query that finds the product with the highest average price, call it `PRODUCTX`, then finds the company with the highest number of sales of `PRODUCTX`, call it `COMPANYX`.

The result should be one row showing `COMPANYX` in one column and the number of sales of PRODUCTX in the other column.

Your help is extremely appreciated.

Comment: Ok, so we don't see your table structure so writing the exact query is not possible. If you edit the post to include structure (and sample data, and hopefully your attempted query) then someone can help you with the answer. But otherwise, all I can tell you is write a query to find the product with the highest price. And write a query to find the customers who sell that product, and COUNT the sales (hints: GROUP BY and IN). That's probably the simplest approach.

Comment: without seeing a table that also shows the number of sales for the product in question this is hard to answer.  Do you have tables for each company, product,sale, and sale price?

Comment: We can use COUNT to find that. @JoshGivens

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
WITH DATAA (id,product,sales_price,company)
AS
(
SELECT 1, 'prod122', 123376456, 'abcSales' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'prod123', 345676433, 'xyzSales' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'prod122', 346876543, 'xyzSales' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'prod124', 124688533, 'wpwSales' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
    D.COMPANY,
    D.PRODUCT,
    T.AVG_PRICE,
    COUNT(1) NO_OF_PRODUCT
FROM
    DATAA D
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            AVG(SALES_PRICE) AVG_PRICE,
            PRODUCT
        FROM
            DATAA
        GROUP BY
            PRODUCT
        ORDER BY
            AVG_PRICE DESC
        FETCH FIRST ROWS ONLY
    ) T ON ( T.PRODUCT = D.PRODUCT )
GROUP BY
    D.COMPANY,
    D.PRODUCT,
    T.AVG_PRICE
ORDER BY
    NO_OF_PRODUCT DESC
FETCH FIRST ROWS ONLY;
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What if multiple products tie for the highest average sale price?
How about if multiple companies tie for the most sales of the product(s) with the highest average sales price?

The query below accounts for these scenarios.  The sales_price in the sample data can be adjusted to examine different scenarios.

```
WITH sample (id,product,sales_price,company)
AS
(
SELECT 1, 'prod100', 10, 'Company 1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'prod122', 10, 'Company 1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'prod123', 10, 'Company 2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'prod123', 10, 'Company 2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'prod123', 10, 'Company 3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'prod123', 10, 'Company 3' FROM DUAL
),
-- Top product(s) by average sales price
top_product AS (
  SELECT *
    FROM (-- Rank the average sales price (ASP) by product
          SELECT product,
            AVG(sales_price) avg_sales_price,
            RANK() OVER (ORDER BY AVG(sales_price) DESC) avg_sales_price_rank
            FROM sample
            GROUP BY product
          )
    WHERE avg_sales_price_rank = 1
),
-- Sales count by company, product
comp_prod_sales AS (
   SELECT company,
          product,
          COUNT(*) sales_count
    FROM sample
    GROUP BY company,
             product
)
-- Top sales of top product(s)
SELECT company,
       product,
       avg_sales_price,
       sales_count
  FROM (SELECT comp_prod_sales.*,
               top_product.avg_sales_price,
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY top_product.product ORDER BY sales_count DESC) sales_count_rank
          FROM top_product,
               comp_prod_sales
          WHERE comp_prod_sales.product = top_product.product)
  WHERE sales_count_rank = 1;
```